# 'int' object is not iterable" when use itertools and apply function to each row

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataset:

```
index    REWARD  
(1,1,1)   0
(1,2,3)   0
(1,1,3)   0
```

I want to set REWARD = 2 if index have a pair of numbers. So output should look like

```
index    REWARD  
(1,1,1)   0
(1,2,3)   0
(1,1,3)   2
```

when I use this code

```
  def set_reward(final):
        for i in final['index']:
            tempCount=[]
            for item,count in collections.Counter((i)).items():
                tempCount.append(count)
            if tempCount==[2, 1] or tempCount==[1, 2]:
                final['REWARD']=2
            return final['REWARD']
    final['REWARD']=final.apply(set_reward,axis=1)
```

It says that 'int' object is not iterable"

Are there any ways to resolve it?

Comment: if you are searching for `2,1` or `1,2` how does `1,3` get reward here? do you mean for this example the pattern should be `1,3`?

Comment: Its not clear what you mean by "index have a pair of numbers". May be you can give few more examples of different index values and which ones you want captures? Or describe in detailed plain English exactly what you want to be captured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the desired result without explicit for looping and conditional logic. Try something like this:

```
# Example data
df = pd.DataFrame({'index':  [(1, 1, 1), (1, 2, 3), (1, 1, 3)], 
                   'REWARD': [0, 0, 2]})


# Select any row whose index contains at least one pair of values
mask = df['index'].apply(lambda x: 2 in Counter(x).values())

df.loc[mask, 'REWARD'] = 2

df
       index  REWARD
0  (1, 1, 1)       0
1  (1, 2, 3)       0
2  (1, 1, 3)       2
```

Comment: Thanks, but the thing is,I want to change size of index and search for pair,set or 2 pairs. That is why I use collections.Counter((i)). I want to have patterns like: [2,1] for pair of numbers if index consists of 3 elements or [2,2,1] for two repeated pairs if index consists of 5 elements

Comment: Ah I see, I've modified my answer to look for any row whose index contains at least one pair, using `Collections.Counter`. Probably not super performant, but it works on small enough datasets.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I wanted. I use mask = final['index'].apply(lambda x: [2,1] == collections.Counter(x).values()), and it works, but what if I want two lists match to collections.Counter(x).values()? How can I use or statement here? I need smth like that:  mask = final['index'].apply(lambda x: [2,1] or [1,2]  == collections.Counter(x).values())